# Add an observer to response using RxAndroid?

Tags: android, android-volley, rx-java, jus

Can anyone give me an example how to add an observer to the response in volley `onResponse()` method using RxJava/Android. I want to observe when the response arrived and trigger some method from other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am working on extended version of volley i call jus.  https://github.com/apptik/jus/ 
there is molude rx-jus whoch implements exactly this. the code is : [here](https://github.com/apptik/jus/tree/master/rx-jus/src/main/java/io/apptik/comm/jus/rx/request)

then when u need to observe  a request u can do :

```
RxRequest.resultObservable(request).subscribe(
                    new Observer<ResultEvent<String>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {
                            System.out.println("requestRX: Completed");
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            System.out.println("requestRX: Error: " + e);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onNext(ResultEvent<String> stringResultEvent) {
                            System.out.println("responseRX: Response: " + stringResultEvent.response);
                        }
                    }
            );
            queue.add(request);
```

in a similar manner u can observe the queue.
you can reuse this for volley just replace the class imports. you can also use jus library instead as it has many handy features and it is similar to volley  :)